# Is there a way to make it a type inference of an array imported as a splice function from different types of tuples?

Tags: typescript, tuples, type-inference

For example, let's say there's a code below.

```
type MyType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const a = [3, 5, 'a', 'b'] as const;

const func = (arg: readonly [number, number, ...MyType[]]) => {
    const myTypeArr = arg.slice(2); // i want this type "MyType[]" !!!
};

func(a);
```

I hope that the "myTypeArr" variable is inferred as MyType[].

However, it is actually inferred as (number | MyType)[].

I did a search to implement it, but I couldn't.

Comment: ① Do you mean "splice" or "slice"? They are different. ② TS doesn't support array methods on tuples the way you want; something similar was suggested for `at` and it was declined as too complex, see [ms/TS#47760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660). You could try to write that type logic yourself if you want, but destructuring is already supported so you could do `[,,...rest]` (ha and I see an answer just appeared saying this part). If you're interested in seeing the type logic to emulate slice on tuples written up as an answer, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz If you write about the topic you mentioned, I will read it.

Comment: I'm not particularly inclined to write out a whole answer for it.  It's complicated to even start, like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1a7lw) would begin to represent it for tuple types of known length, but does not work the way you want for open-ended tuples, so more work would need to be done there.  It's certainly not worth trying to force TS to understand such things when array destructuring is already implemented natively.

Comment: [Here's a version](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1Xvm) that works for `arr.slice(n)` where `n` is a non-negative integer of known literal type.  Still not worth doing it as an implementation, but maybe I'll write up an answer sometime for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use destructuring to achieve this:

```
type MyType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const a = [3, 5, 'a', 'b'] as const;

const func = (arg: readonly [number, number, ...MyType[]]) => {
    // myTypeArr will have type MyType[]
    const [ , , ...myTypeArr] = arg;
};

func(a);
```